# Where do DLLs go for Emacs 24.4.1 on Windows 7?

Tags: emacs24.4, microsoft-windows

I'm getting the message "zlib library not found" when I start emacs and I found that [I need to download zlib](https://github.com/vermiculus/sx.el/issues/157), which is fine. Then I need to put the DLL somewhere, but I can't find where that should be.

Where do the DLLs that emacs depends on need to go?

Comment: I'd try to put it in the `bin` directory near `emacs` executable.

Comment: That was a lucky guess, maybe people building Emacs on Windows will explain it better (there may be more than one place where Emacs looks for libraries for example).

Comment: See also [this question](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/3874/easiest-way-to-install-emacs-windows-support-libraries).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have two choices:

1. Place all the associated libraries within the `emacs\bin` folder.  This will allow them to be linked as needed
2. Place all associated libraries in a folder found on you `%PATH%`.  I prefer doing it this way because it ensures that I keep the libraries in place following upgrades.

   ```
   c:\bin\
        +- emacs\ (directory softlink to desired emacs version
        +- emacs-libs\
        `- emacs-<version>\
                        `- bin
   ```

`c:\bin\emacs\bin\` and `c:\bin\emacs-libs\` are both stored on my `%PATH%`, like this I can keep older versions if necessary (change the softlink when needed) and `emacs-libs` will contain the valid `.dll`s so that I do not need to copy them over when updating.